# A duplicate's originals can't be rearranged

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

The [multi-duplicate feature announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) clearly states that gold badge holders can change the order of a duplicate question's listing of originals:

> As of a few minutes ago, if you have a gold tag-badge for a tag associated with a question that's been closed as a duplicate, you can edit the duplicate links to replace, add, remove **or re-arrange** them:

(emphasis added)

But when I go into the interface for editing originals, I don't see any way to rearrange them. Click-and-drag doesn't do it, there are no "move up" or "move down" arrows, and I don't see any other familiar UI conventions for this task. I tried removing and re-adding originals in a different order, but, after saving, the order always ends up unchanged.

Either this feature is far too hard to find, or it's just plain missing.

Comment: "I tried removing and re-adding originals in a different order, but, after saving, the order always ends up unchanged." No familiar UI conventions is one thing. This actually makes it hilarious.

Comment: This would be nice to have. The first time I used the new feature, I also left a comment that began with "The first duplicate answers your literal question [...]" -- except that the "first duplicate" wasn't. Thankfully, I had another look at the duplicate list before leaving the question!

Comment: just noticed that original feature announcement encourages you to use [exact-duplicates] tag for bug reports like this, but you can't, since it's considered a duplicate of [duplicate-questions] and you cannot rearrange them in a way they would match what was requested...

Comment: @eis - it was requested so *on a different site* than this.

Comment: Afair, removing and adding in different order did work for me. Though maybe I also changed more than just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The announcement post was incorrect - there was no reordering feature for duplicates when it was released.

It does now.

Enjoy!

Comment: "The announcement post was incorrect" [:(](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverTrustATrailer) "It does now." [:D](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubvertedTrope)

Comment: The new feature is discoverable, intuitive, and functional. [Neat!](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/714/256/eb4.jpg)